# QT_API environment variable

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use [formlayout](https://pypi.org/project/formlayout/) and I'm finally transitioning to PyQt5. formlayout is failing to import on:

```
ImportError: formlayout requires PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide
```

It looks like the issue is that my QT_API environment variable isn't set and the module defaults to PyQt4. I could set the environment variable to PyQt5, but I go back and forth between Anaconda environments with PyQt4 and PyQt5 so I would rather not have to manually set that each time. Am I missing something? How is that environment variable normally set?

It seems like the module could attempt to import either version without looking at the QT_API but I suspect I'm missing the intent.

I'm using python 2.7.13, pyqt 5.6.0 and formlayout 1.1.0.

Comment: test importing PyQt5 first before the formlayout, something like: `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` `from formlayout import fedit`

Comment: That still fails with the same error. Importing PyQt5 doesn't seem to set QT_API.

Comment: Your question is to set QT_API globally?

Comment: Sorry, no, I could set it globally but then I'd have to change it when I move between environments. It seems from the design of formlayout, it is expected that it would be set, and I'm wondering if there's a way that it is set other than the global OS environment variable.

Comment: use `import os` `os.environ["QT_API"] = "pyqt5"`

Comment: That would work but it doesn't seem ideal because I'd have to do it anytime I use formlayout. I guess I wonder if this is a bug in formlayout or if there are other PyQt modules that work this way.

Comment: It is not a mistake, it is the backend pre-established by Anaconda, formlayout does not know Anaconda or is interested (ie the developer maybe did not think about the compatibility with Anaconda), I do not know what magic answer you expect, you do not want to establish it globally, so you I show a solution for each project and does not want it either.

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for a magic answer, I'm trying to learn. I can make any of your suggestions work, but I'm trying to understand better. I think the first part of your last comment may be getting to my question. What is different about anaconda than other distributions in this context?

Comment: It's not that it's special, it's just that you might use PyQt4 as default backend, that's something inexplicable, in my case I have both: PyQt4 and PyQt5, I do not use anaconda for version reasons and I can import that library without problems.

Comment: Do you have QT_API set globally?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: I'm in Windows 10

Comment: @LC_ You can [see for yourself](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/formlayout/blob/master/formlayout.py#L50) exactly how the default API is chosen. If you want that to change, you can simply include the `formlayout` module in your own project and modify it in whatever way you like (the code has an [MIT Licence](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/formlayout/blob/master/LICENSE)). The developer hasn't made any commits for almost three years, so maintaining a personal fork won't be a significant burden.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'd considered that as an option as well. Ultimately I suspect that's what I'll end up doing. I'm just trying to understand how this is typically done because if there was something I was missing in setting up my environments, I'd rather correct that then modify a stable PyPI module that otherwise works fine. I just haven't encountered this use of the QT_API variable. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @LC_ If you read the actual code (which is very simple), you will see that forking is your ***only*** option, because the defaults are hard-coded. There is nothing that can be done externally to change that.

Comment: Okay, that answers my question then. I understood how the code worked, which is why I asked the question. I thought I must be missing something about how the environment variable is intended to be used. Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on feedback from ekhumoro and eyllanesc, and [issue 87](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/formlayout/issues/87) and [88](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/formlayout/pull/88), I think there are a few options:

1. Assign the QT_API environment variably globally.
2. Assign the variable on a per-project basis using `import os os.environ["QT_API"] = "pyqt5"`
3. Fork [formlayout](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/formlayout) and "fix" the dependency check logic.